# Using design patterns in laravel 5

Tags: design-patterns, laravel-5, php-5.6

What  are the design patterns that we can use in large projects with Laravel 5 ? is there any good tutorials or books to learn those design patterns ?

Comment: Containers, Subsriber, Visitor and plainty others design pattern are used in Laravel. You can them as well too. You can still check this book : https://goo.gl/hQ0IVP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Building a large project can't be solved by just applying some design patterns, you need to dive a little more deeper and learn about architectural patterns, to find which one is the closest to your project case, and apply it. In most of the times you can merge multiple architectural patterns together to get a full solution.

**Design patterns:** Solves re-occurring problems in software construction.

**Architectural patterns:** Fundamental structural organization for software systems.

For more details about design patterns you can check this nice article http://www.mahmoudzalt.com/blog/software-design-patterns/

However I will list to you some of the interesting Architectural Patterns that I used to apply before coming with my own one

- Ports and Adapters (Layered Architecture)

  - Hexagonal Architecture
  - Onion Architecture
  - Clean Architecture
- Domain Driven Design Pattern
- CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation)
- Event Sourcing
- Use Case Driven Development or use case architecture
- Command oriented interfaces
- Domain-events
- Repository Pattern
- Micro-Services Architecture Pattern

  - layered architecture pattern

    (monolithic architecture)
  - service oriented architecture

    (distributed applications architecture)
- IODA Architecture